# Difference between Analytics and XDB Contact

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am working with `Sitecore Analytics version 9 update 2`.

There are two contact reference name

1. Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact
2. Sitecore.XConnect.Contact

Can anyone please elaborate what is the difference between both where which contact type we will use? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different models used for different purposes. To quote [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/web-tracking-217852.html):

The **tracker uses its own model** (`Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact`) to represent contacts, interactions, and events. It does not use the xConnect model. **On session end, data** collected by the tracker **is converted** to a format that can be used by xConnect (`Sitecore.XConnect.Contact`). For example, `Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Entities.IContact` is converted to `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact`.

- Use `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact` for contact tracking purposes.
- Use `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact` to save/load contact data to xConnect.

Comment: Hello grg, Do you have any idea how can I convert/cast `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Contact` to `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact`.

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat, there is no direct casting, but have a look at xConnect conversion pipelines: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/conversion-pipelines.html